# Java's new Base64(-1) in PHP?

Tags: java, php, base64

I m trying to match java base64 code in php. But getting inconsistent result.

**Java base64 encode**

```
encMessage = URLEncoder.encode(new Base64(-1).encodeToString(encrypted),"UTF8");
```

Java decode

```
message = URLDecoder.decode(message,"utf8");
```

Above code java encode code return the string which i have to decode and decrypt in php

**PHP base64 decode**

```
$message     = utf8_decode(urldecode($encrypted));
$message     = base64_decode($message);
```

PHP encode

```
$encMessage     = base64_encode($encrypted);
$encMessage     = utf8_encode(urlencode($encMessage));
```

Results:
java:

```
KO%2F%2B%2Bzbp5z8oCdvZn62jb72kseT%2Bem8hYUZY0IuB9zo%3D
```

php:

```
KO%2F%2B%2Bzbp5z8oCdvZn62jb3CVVVXsV%2Bws2kDOmKK%2BPEc%3D
```

src : https://gist.github.com/944269

Comment: What is your question? What happens? Can you show some examples?

Comment: I dont see any results :? Note, that you not only Base64-encode the string, but also URLEncode, which (afaik) works slightly different in both languages. http://php.net/rawurlencode

Comment: You have `urldecode` on both sides in PHP. Is that intentional?

Comment: java: KO%2F%2B%2Bzbp5z8oCdvZn62jb72kseT%2Bem8hYUZY0IuB9zo%3D
php:  KO%2F%2B%2Bzbp5z8oCdvZn62jb3CVVVXsV%2Bws2kDOmKK%2BPEc%3D

Comment: i m passing this string thru url (thats why i used urlencode). You see above base64 in from java and php are different.

Comment: When trying to decode your example strings, I just see a bunch of bytes, that arent even characters. That all doesnt make much sense. A base64-encoded is always url-safe, so no need for url-encode (or vice versa). What you are trying to achieve?!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/944269 http://zdev.uni.cc/sof/test.php

Comment: What's you Base64 method in Java up to 1.6.0_18 at least. AFAIK this is not a method included in the JDK is it a 3rd part library? I'm not sure base64 is "url safe" but at any rate there is no need to perform any UTF8 encode/decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem between CSharp and Java, and found that URL encoding things was the culprit. What I did in my work around was basically re-encrypt the data with a newly generated public key until I got one that didn't need URL encoding. Not a great solution, but it works, it averages 2 tries to get it right, but I've seen it taking up to 15 tries to do it, either way we're still talking milliseconds, and it works reliably.

YMMV

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over java side. I have to grab the encrypted data in php then decrypt and base64_decode it. Unfortunately result is very inconsistent. Check test link